# Какая разница между 32-х битной программой и 64-х?

Tags: c++

1. Какая разница между 32-х битной программой и 64-х ?
2. Если я пишу код в 64-х битной ОС на С++ это будет 64-х битной программой ?
3. Как написать 64-х битную программу ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Размер типов long и указателей (64 и 32 бит). 
   В принципе 64-бит программа может непосредственно обращаться к данным в  адресном пространстве большем 4 гигабайта, а 32-бит - не может.
   Иногда 32-бит программы работают быстрее (в основном из-за более экономного использования кэша CPU).
   64-бит программы не могут исполняться на 32-бит машинах, а наоборот можно (но не всегда).
2. Если компилятор 64-битный, то да.
3. Используйте 64-бит ОС и 64-бит компилятор.

Comment: @avp, огромное вам спасибо ...

Comment: Уточнение к 2 - если компилятор умеет генерировать 64-битный код. А сам он хоть восьмибитным может быть.

Comment: @avp,  о п.3: можно скомпилировать 64-битную программу и в 32-битной ОС, если компилятор может генерировать 64-битный код (я такие примеры знаю). Другое дело, что такую программу на этой ОС не запустишь )))

Comment: Конечно можно. Даже для другого процессора. 

Вы это точно знаете, а для ТС - такие штучки называются *кросс компиляция*.

Просто я решил глубоко в тему не вдаваться (уже ночью отвечал), остановиться на практически важном для новичка (насколько хорошо получилось, не знаю).

Answer (score 0):

> Какая разница между 32-х битной программой и 64-х ?

Это определяется вашим компилятором и тем, что он решит изменить в свойствах С++-платформы при переключении между 32-битной и 64-битной конфигурациями. Обычно меняется размер всех указательных типов. Могут также поменяться размеры фундаментальных целочисленных типов и т.п.

> Если я пишу код в 64-х битной ОС на С++ это будет 64-х битной программой ?

Нет. Ваша ОС здесь не играет никакой роли вообще. Все определяется только компилятором и его настройками.

> Как написать 64-х битную программу ?

??? Так же, как и 32-битную программу. Сесть и написать. Ничего другого, вроде, пока не придумали.